# Android Honeycomb and imeOptions

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-edittext, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have an application with a EditText with the following properties:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sendText"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:hint="Message"
>
```

On my phone running Froyo, I get the "Send" action button in the keyboard, which `android:imeOptions="actionSend"`should do, but on my Xoom running Honeycomb, the keyboard gets no action button, and I cannot use the send action.

Was there a change in the API for honeycomb, or is there a bug? Or something else I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still not sure if it's a bug or an API change, but adding the `android:inputType="text"` property to the EditText's definition causes the Enter button to use the proper imeOption action!

This can be further confirmed with a third party keyboard, such as Swiftkey Beta for Tablets, as its action button changes into a "Send" button as non-tablet versions of Android do with their default keyboards.